# Java: Image upload with JavaScript - File is damaged, corrupted or too large

Tags: javascript, java, spring, file-upload, corrupt-data

I am using **Spring Boot** as backend server and I have a **JavaScript** frontend.
For sending data between front- and backend I'm using the **[Axios library](https://github.com/axios/axios)**, which usually works pretty fine.


**The Problem:**
The image looks like this in the (Chrome) browser console:
[image: Console output]
It's a very very long alphanumeric string and that's what I send to the server with the following code:

```
static uploadFiles(files) {
    const data = new FormData();

    Object.keys(files).forEach(key => {
        data.append("files", new Blob([files[key]], { type: 'image/jpeg' }));
    });

    const url = API_URL + "uploadFiles";
    return axios.post(url, data, RestServices.getAuth({
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p"
    }));
}
```

I have no idea what the `boundary` thing does but it worked to receive a file in the backend tho...

On backend (spring) side I successfully receive an array of MultipartFiles:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFiles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean uploadFiles(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException {
    String filePath = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("assets/images/").getFile();
    InputStream inputStream;
    OutputStream outputStream;
    for(MultipartFile file : files) {
        File newFile = new File(filePath + file.getOriginalFilename() + ".jpg");
        inputStream = file.getInputStream();

        if (!newFile.exists() && newFile.createNewFile()) {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            int read;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(newFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've also tried it `file.transferTo(newFile);` instead of in- and outputstreams - which didn't work either.
After that I get the following output, which means that the image was saved successfully:
`/path/to/blob.jpg`
If I check the path where the file was uploaded, there is a file named blob.jpg, but if I open it, the windows photo viewer has the following problem:
[image: Error in windows photo viewer]
I've opened the image before and after upload with notepad++:
**Before** upload:
[image: Image before upload (Byte Array)]
I think this is a byte array, but If I open the image **after** upload I get **exactly** the output of the browser. This means it didn't get converted to a byte array (correct me if I'm wrong) and I believe that's why it's a corrupt image...

My questions are:

- **What's** the problem?
- **How** can I **fix** it?

I really tried everything which crossed my mind but I ran out of ideas.

Thanks for your help! :-)

I've read following *related* questions (but they **don't** have an answer):
[Question1][5], [Question2][6], and **many** more...

Comment: Basically it's the difference between sending bytes or Base64 encoded bytes.

Comment: Meanwhile I've tried this: `outputStream.write(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes), 0, read);`, but still the same error. Maybe there's a problem with encoding the image prefix (data:image/jpeg)? @Kayaman But I don't even know which type (encoded or not) I'm sending...

Comment: You can't "decrypt" a hash. It's a one way function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've finally found an answer on my own! 
I think the problem was that I used the `e.target.result` (which is used to show the image on the frontend) but insted I had to use the [JS File object](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/File). The standard HTML 5 file input fields return those File objects (as I've read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)). 
The only thing I had to do now is to make a FormData object, append the File Object, set the FormData as Body and set the Content-Type header and that's it!

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("files", fileObject);
return axios.post(url, data, {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
});
```

Those JS File Objects are recognized from Java as Multipart files:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFiles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean uploadFiles(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) {

    boolean transferSuccessful = true;

    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
        String extension = file.getOriginalFilename().substring(file.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf('.'));

        String newFileName = genRandomName() + extension; //set unique name when saving on server
        File newFile;

        File imageFolder = new File(imageBasePath);
        //check if parent folders exist else create it
        if(imageFolder .exists() || imageFolder .mkdirs()) {
            while ((newFile = new File(imageFolder .getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + newFileName)).exists()) {
                newFileName = genRandomName(); //generate new name if file already exists
            }
            try {
                file.transferTo(newFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                transferSuccessful = false;
            }
        } else {
            LOG.error("Could not create folder at " + imageFolder.getAbsolutePath());
            transferSuccessful = false;
        }
    }
    return transferSuccessful;
}
```

I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Great answer. saved my day

Comment: How did you convert the e.target.result File to a JS File object?

Comment: You automatically get a File object if you use an input field with type 'file' see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file